# nhibernate many to many mapping via code

Tags: postgresql, nhibernate

I have an entity class:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public virtual IList<Item> OriginItems {get; set;}
    public virtual IList<Item> ResultItems {get; set;}
}
```

As you can see, there are two lists of `Item` objects, which I need to represent in my db with many-to-many relationship.

Here's my script for association table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE public.item_transformation
(
   origin_item_id integer NOT NULL,
   result_item_id integer NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT result_fkey FOREIGN KEY (result_item_id)
       REFERENCES public.item (id) MATCH SIMPLE
       ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
   CONSTRAINT origin__fkey FOREIGN KEY (origin_item_id)
       REFERENCES public.item (id) MATCH SIMPLE
       ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

);

Now, my question is how to define many-to-many mappings for such case via code and how about constraints on association table `ItemTransformation` - how to set them properly?

UPDATE:
For now I have such mapping code:

```
        Bag(u => u.OriginItems, map =>
        {
            map.Table("item_transformation");
            map.Key(k => k.Column("origin_item_id"));
        }, ce => ce.ManyToMany(m =>
        {
            m.Column("result_item_id");
        }));

        Bag(u => u.ResultItems, map =>
        {
            map.Table("item_transformation");
            map.Key(k => k.Column("result_item_id"));
        }, ce => ce.ManyToMany(m =>
        {
            m.Column("origin_item_id");
        }));
```

But it apperas that values which are for `origin_item_id` are saved in `result_item_id` and vice versa - they have swapped places.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Names for my Ids are identical, as you can see above - there is my whole code, as it looks now, I cannot find any naming differences

Comment: Solved  thanks. But now I have one more problem - see updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how it should be done:

```
    Bag(u => u.OriginItems, map =>
    {
        map.Table("item_transformation");
        map.Key(k => k.Column("result_item_id")); // swapped
    }, ce => ce.ManyToMany(m =>
    {
        m.Column("origin_item_id"); // swapped
    }));

    Bag(u => u.ResultItems, map =>
    {
        map.Table("item_transformation");
        map.Key(k => k.Column("origin_item_id")); // spapped
    }, ce => ce.ManyToMany(m =>
    {
        m.Column("result_item_id"); // swapped
    }));
```